# Failed to send email: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: typescript, next.js, nodemailer

I created contact form using next.js and want to send email to my gmail adress. But i get this error ("Failed to send email: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.")
Even if u enabled 2 way varification and using pass that is generated via app password gmail. Also my user name and pass are 100% correct

(Failed to send email: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z5-20020a170906434500b00977cad140a8sm6880619ejm.218 - gsmtp
at SMTPConnection._formatError (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:424:15)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:1003:30)
at SMTPConnection.eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:253:22)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:534:16)
at SMTPConnection._onData (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:397:10)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:343:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:316:9)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:253:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
'535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z5-20020a170906434500b00977cad140a8sm6880619ejm.218 - gsmtp',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}

i tried everthing.....